# Unity3d EasyAR Target loads at the start of the camera before find the trarget

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I am tring to build an AR android app with unity3d last version and EASYAR SDK. 
I have create the target and i am able to load my image or video at it's chile object but the child objct (cube or plane) load imediately when th camera opens.

i am looking some help on how i can apear the image or start the video when the camera find the target and not when the app starts.

thnns a lot in advanced guys for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable them in the beginning and modify the OnTargetFound event of the ImageTargetBehaviour script to enable them. Something like this:

```c#
public GameObject myARObject;

void OnTargetFound(TargetAbstractBehaviour behaviour)
{
    Debug.Log("Found: " + Target.Id);
    myARObject.SetActive (true);
}
```

Hope this helps.